# l'Hospital rule

Tags: limits

The condition for l'Hospital rule is that after substituting variables with values the limit has to be in the form

$$\frac00\quad\text{or}\quad \frac\infty\infty$$

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} x^2  \sin x$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^m-1}{x^n-1}$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$

What about this cases , are the rules fulfiled?

Comment: First limit is straight forward. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} x^2  \sin x$=0 but what do you think about $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} x^2  cosec x$ ?

Answer (score 3):

One often forgets an essential condition to apply L'Hospital's rule: the  denominator must not be $0$ in some neighbourhood  of the point at which we compute the limit, except at this point.

Comment: Interesting point, could you please provide a hint for how to check for this condition? Thx.

Comment: Usually, there is no problem: most functions have isolated roots. You may have difficulties with functions like $\; x\sin \dfrac1x$ in the neighbourhood of $0$. There is no general strategy, as far as I know. Let me add, most of the tima L'Hospital's rule should be avoided: it is logically equivalent  to using Taylor's formula at order $1$, which doesn't have this drawback.

Comment: I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!

Comment: @Bernard: You need a different example. L'hospital doesn't apply to x sin(1/x) anyway, because there is no quotient with limits 0/0 or inf/inf.

Comment: @gnasher729: Maybe my comment wasn't clear enough: I didn't mean applying L'Hospital to this case, I only meant ‘If the `denominator` involves a function of this kind’.

Answer (score 2):

For the first limit, the limit is simply $0$, there is no fraction. For, the second, yes it is of the form $0/0$ and you can apply L'Hopital's rule since both terms - numerator and denominator - are polynomials and hence differentiable. It will give you $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^m-1}{x^n-1}\overset{\frac00}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(x^m-1)'}{(x^n-1)'}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{mx^{m-1}}{nx^{n-1}}=\frac{m\cdot1}{n\cdot1}=\frac{m}{n}$$ for $m,n \in \mathbb N_{>0}$.

Comment: For the second one, I think that the limit is just $\frac mn$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You are correct. I was thinking about $x\to \infty$. Let me edit my answer.